# How can I continue sending to stdin after input from bash process substitution finishes?

Tags: linux, bash, gdb, pipe, stdin

I'm using `gdb`.

I run a command like the below to set up the program by sending it input to stdin:

`r < <(python -c "print '1\n2\n3'")`

I want that command to allow me to start typing input after it finishes (so I can interact with the debugee normally) instead of stdin being closed.

This would work in bash but you can't pipe to the gdb `r` command this way:

`cat <(python -c "print '1\n2\n3'") - | r`

The below doesn't work, I assume it waits for EOF before it sends it to the program.

`r < <(cat <(python -c "print '1\n2\n3'") -)`

Is there a third option that will work?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a job for [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/).

Given

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char *cp = NULL;
  size_t n = 0;


  while(getline(&cp, &n, stdin) >= 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "got: %s", cp);
  }

  return 0;
}

gcc -g -Wall t.c
```

And this expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn gdb -q ./a.out

send run\n
send 1\n2\n3\n

interact
```

Here is the session:

```
$ ./t.exp
spawn gdb -q ./a.out
run
1
2
3
Reading symbols from ./a.out...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/a.out
got: 1
got: 2
got: 3
```

Now the script is waiting for my input. I provide some:

```
foo bar baz
got: foo bar baz
```

I can also interact with GDB:

```
^C
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x00007ffff7b006b0 in __read_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
81  ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7b006b0 in __read_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
#1  0x00007ffff7a8f5a0 in _IO_new_file_underflow (fp=0x7ffff7dd4640 <_IO_2_1_stdin_>) at fileops.c:613
#2  0x00007ffff7a840d5 in _IO_getdelim (lineptr=0x7fffffffdda0, n=0x7fffffffdda8, delimiter=10, fp=0x7ffff7dd4640 <_IO_2_1_stdin_>) at iogetdelim.c:77
#3  0x000000000040064e in main () at t.c:9
```

Comment: I like the answer although I'm still hoping for a one-liner from inside gdb.